# Run time and space complexity for Power function using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static long pow_2(long x, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return x;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return pow_2( x, n / 2 ) * pow_2( x, n / 2 );
     }    
    else {
        return pow_2(x * x, n / 2) * x;
     }
}
```

Is the Space complexity not OLog(n), since your are making n/2 calls to the stack main frame at each call?

Is the time complexity not O(2^n) since we make two calls from the function each time?

I'm using java by the way.

Comment: Certainly, it should be squaring the result of `pow_2(x, n / 2)` as this is being calculated twice etc.

Answer (score 0):

the time complexity is not 2^n because the two recursive calls end much faster than in linear time. You're recursive formula follows T(n) = 2*T(n/2) for the case where n is a power of 2 (which is the worst case). By the master theorem: http://www.cse.unt.edu/~tarau/teaching/cf1/Master%20theorem.pdf
you have that c = 0 < log_b a which is 1. Thus the complexity of the function is O(n). This is similar to an in-order traversal.

Comment: So what would be the time complexity and what would be the space complexity?

Comment: Runtime is O(n). the space complexity is O(logn).